# Unable to recognise deletion of profile image and show gravatar

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, cloudinary

Im using Meteor and Cloudinary to display upload and display profile image.

**Problem**
After profile image is deleted (via image id), the field profilepicId remains, but it shows undefined. Hence helpers cannot seem to pick up whether the profilepicId exist or not and constantly shows Gravatar (although theres an uploaded image) OR does not show any gravatar when image is deleted.

Using Mongol, the field shows `"profilepicId": {}`

**Console when image is uploaded (shows length but value undefined?)** 

[image: When img is uploaded and exists]

**Console when image is deleted (all undefined)** 

[image: When img deleted]

**profile html**

```
{{#with currentUser}}
   {{#if profilepicId}}
       <img src="{{c.url profilepicId format=format gravity='faces' mode='thumb' crop='thumb' width=60 height=60}}">
   {{else}} 
       <div class="avatar" style="background: url({{avatar 40}}); height: 50px; width: 50px; float:left;"></div>
   {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

**profile js**

```
Template.profile.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;
   self.autorun(function(){
      self.subscribe('user', Meteor.userId());
      $.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: "XX", api_key: 'XX' }); 
   });
});

Template.profile.helpers({
   user: function () {
      return Meteor.user(); 
   },
   profilepicId: function (){ 
      var u = Meteor.user().profile; 
      if( u.profilepicId === undefined || u.profilepicId === null){ 
         return false
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you `unset` that field after deleting the image?

Comment: @Khang What do you mean and how should I go about unsetting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the first things you indicate is:

> Using Mongol, the field shows "profilepicId": {}

... but you're checking to see if that's undefined, if i understand what you're saying. are you saying that, once the image is deleted, that field is an empty JSON object? because that is *not* undefined. in that case, where is the code that updates the profile when the image is deleted?

that aside, your code can be greatly simplified.

first, i don't think you don't need a helper to get the profilepicId. you can do that all with currentUser in Blaze:

```
{{#with currentUser}}
   {{#if profile.profilepicId}}
       <img src="{{c.url profile.profilepicId format=format gravity='faces' mode='thumb' crop='thumb' width=60 height=60}}">
   {{else}} 
       <!-- gravatar -->
   {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

let's look at your onCreated():

```
Template.profile.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;
   self.autorun(function(){
      self.subscribe('user', Meteor.userId());
      $.cloudinary.config({ cloud_name: "XX", api_key: 'XX' }); 
   });
});
```

1. does this template get updated in place when the user changes? if not, why is there an autorun?
2. what is this "user" subscription? does it do something the normal user publish doesn't do?
3. why are you configuring cloudinary so many times? it needs to be done only once (e.g. at client startup)
4. why are you putting your api_key on the client? that data is needed only for the server config. the client config only needs the cloud_name. the api_key on the client is insecure.

unless there's something i don't understand (most likely due to #2), i don't think you need anything in there. (and the config gets moved to client start, of course).

and i don't see anything in the helpers you need, either, since you can drive everything off currentUser in Blaze.

so, in short, what does Meteor.user().profile look like when the profile image is deleted, and what is that code doing? i.e. is that field truly undefined, or an empty JSON object?

**update**:

for Cloudinary config, i have this on the client (client/index.js):

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    $.cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: Meteor.settings.public.cloudinary.cloud_name
    });
}
```

i pull the info from a settings file, but you can hardcode it to get started.

on the server (server/startup/cloudinaryConfig.js):

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Cloudinary.config({
        cloud_name: Meteor.settings.private.cloudinary.cloud_name,
        api_key: Meteor.settings.private.cloudinary.api_key,
        api_secret: Meteor.settings.private.cloudinary.api_secret
    });
});
```

to set that up, my settings.json has this structure:

```
{
    "public": {
        "cloudinary": {
            "cloud_name": "foo"
        }
    },
    "private": {
        "cloudinary": {
            "cloud_name": "foo",
            "api_key": "xxx",
            "api_secret": "yyy"
        },
    }
}
```

oh, it's worth mentioning that i'm using this package (i think you're using the same): https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/cloudinary

Comment: Thanks @Zim. Mongol shows `profilepicId: { }` after deletion (i.e no more id string stored in the field). I said it wrongly. In console log (see pic 2), the field shows object but value and count of it shows undefined. Somehow the html suggested changes dont work. Gravatar doesnt show up without helper and html. For OnCreated, [1] the current user no change. Theres a separate html for all other users which do change with the user. [2] no use, removed it. [3] where should I put it? In library folder? [4] think i tried api in config.js within server folder but somehow didnt work?

Comment: Sorry it is indeed working now after making changes and including @Khang's suggestion. Since yours is the main bulk, will tick yours as the answer. Thanks. 

Appreciate if you can answer the replies for #1 (if not autorun, how should I write it?) and 3. Would you know how to have preview of image and uploading progress bar? I followed docs but now its a little mashed up.

Comment: for the progress bar, i don't know how, sorry. i just show a generic page spinner. for the autorun() question, i don't understand. if the cloudinary setup gets moved, and you got rid of the subscribe, your autorun() is now empty. so why do you need it? "currentUser" in the html is reactive all on its own.

Comment: Good point, I have some console.log to check for correct user ID on page load. As for settings.json, I'm quite a newbie on this. Havent been able to set up and run an app on settings.json. I've read about it though on the public and private keys for security purposes. Also yes I'm using the same lepozos package.

Comment: you can hardcode for now. but if you want to get it going, you can copy/paste all three updated snippets and put it in the file names i indicated. then, instead of "meteor" to start, it's "meteor --settings settings.json"

Comment: Hi zim, would you know how to display profile image of other users? I tried                               `{{#if profile.profilepicId}} <img src="{{c.url profile.profilepicId format=format gravity='faces' mode='thumb' crop='thumb' width=60 height=60}}">`. Worked with a `{{#with currentUser}}` or `{{#with user}}` but not for a list of groups with multiple users.

Comment: @Thinkerer, you need to supply more code. either update your answer or ask a brand new question. it's going to have to do w/ how you're publishing the user data for the other users.

Comment: here it is for easier reading
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328237/how-to-show-another-users-profile-image-item-with-meteor-cloudinary

Answer (score 1):

After deleting your images, you should also delete the `profilepicId` field with `$unset` operator:

```
Meteor.users.update({
  _id: userId
}, {
  $unset: {
    'profile.profilepicId': '',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks I had a `$set : { 'profilepicId': {}}` and that created an empty array.