# How to show another user's profile image item with Meteor Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Theres 2 issues.

**Firstly**: Once a room is started, theres 2 people in it, owner and receiver. I am unable to display the other person's profile image in the list of rooms. I can see my own image thats is uploaded via Cloudinary, saved under profile --> profilepicId as an Id which then generates an image.

**Secondly**: I cannot retrieve posts of a user when I go to user's page. Server throws a id match error. Sometimes it also hangs and I will not be able to view my own posts when i go to my profile page.

**Update**: The Rooms collection are structure as follows: Each room will contain                owner, receiver, people:[ owner , receiver ] and roomId.

**Server error**

> ```
> > Exception from sub user id JS9gKeT4sXNDCwip6 Error: Match error:
> > Expected string, got undefined I20170410-23:28:59.972(8)?     at
> > exports.check (packages/check/match.js:34:1)
> > I20170410-23:28:59.972(8)?     at Subscription.<anonymous>
> > (server/server.js:88:2) I20170410-23:28:59.973(8)?     at
> > (packages/reywood_publish-composite/packages/reywood_publish-composite.js:440:1)
> > I20170410-23:28:59.973(8)? at Subscription._handler
> > (packages/reywood_publish-composite/packages/reywood_publish-composite.js:408:1)
> > at Object.exports.Match._failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked
> ```

**publish.js**

```
Meteor.publish('userDetails', function() {
   var fields = { username: 1, emails   : 1, profile : 1, md5hash : 1 };
   return Meteor.users.find( {}, { fields: fields });
});
Meteor.publishComposite('user', function (_id) {
  check(_id, String);
  //if (!_id) return this.ready(); doesnt help remove error
  return {
     find: function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({ _id: _id }, { 
          fields: { username: 1, emails: 1, profile : 1, md5hash: 1}
        });
     }, children: [....]
    };
 });
```

**roomCollection.js** - im using dburles:collection-helpers

```
Rooms.helpers({ 
   chatPerson: function(){
      if( this.owner === Meteor.userId() ) {
         return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.receiver }).username; 
      } else {
         return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.owner }).username;
      }
   }
});
```

I can see the user's profile image but not the posts of a specific user + server match error.

**user.html**

```
{{#with user}}
    {{#if profile.profilepicId}}  
      <img src="....."> <!-- can see profile pic --> 
    {{/if}}
    {{#each posts}}     <!-- cannot see posts + server match error --> 
       {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

**user.js**

```
Template.usersShow.onCreated(function(){
   var self = this;
   self.autorun(function(){
      self.subscribe('rooms');
      self.subscribe('user', Router.current().params._id);
   });
});
Template.usersShow.helpers({
   posts: function () {
      return Posts.find({ userId: Router.current().params._id });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your publication expects a parameter:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('user', function (_id) { ... })
```

But your subscription is not passing a param:

```
self.subscribe('user');
```

Now, one should *never* pass the current user's `_id` from the client as it is not trusted - it could be a spoofed value and it's available on the server anyway.

Also you don't need to use `publishComposite` here because you only ever have one parent. Instead you can return an array of cursors:

```
Meteor.publish('me', () => {   
  if (!this.userId) this.ready(); // since the rest is pointless
  else return [
     Meteor.users.find(this.userId, { 
       fields: { username: 1, emails: 1, profile : 1, md5hash: 1}
     }), 
     Posts.find({ userId: this.userId })
  ];
 });
```

If you need to see the details of a *different user* on the client then you need to publish that with an `_id` parameter *and* include that in your subscription. You still don't need publish-composite in this particular case.

server:

```
Meteor.publish('otherUser', (_id) => {   
  if (!this.userId) this.ready();
  else {
    check(_id,String);
    return [
      Meteor.users.find(_id, { 
        fields: { username: 1, emails: 1, profile : 1, md5hash: 1}
      }), 
      Posts.find({ userId: _id })
    ];
   }
 });
```

client:

```
self.subscribe('otherUser',otherUserId); // you must pass a param
```

Also you can simplify:

```
chatPersonId: function(){
  if( this.owner === Meteor.userId() ) {
     return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.receiver })._id;
  } else {
     return Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.owner })._id;
  }
},
```

Down to:

```
chatPersonId() {
  return this.owner === Meteor.userId() ? this.receiver : this.owner;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michel. I used to do it like above but somehow there were issues showing posts reactively. I'll try and get back on the results. Does that also  mean I can remove the first userDetail publication?

Comment: What issues did you have with showing posts reactively? Should work. And yes, your `userDetails` publication is redundant.

Comment: I removed both pubs and replace with the above. I could get screen to appear and work with `Meteor.publish('user', function(){ ....`. I can view my posts but cannot view posts of another user. Adding `check(userId, String)` does not do anything. Server error: Exception from sub user id mjCzowgwB3ZynQf6e Error: Did not check() all arguments during publisher 'user'. 

The entire list of chats are also now gone, server error: ` Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` where id is the one in chatPerson collection helper.

Comment: If you're looking at multiple other users at once then you probably need to keep publishing your `userDetails` publication since it finds all users.

Comment: Great, adding the publish works, names appear. How to make the profile images of my chat opponent appear in the list of rooms? I tried adding helper that says `Meteor.users.findOne({ people: { $ne: Meteor.userId() } });` but so far its glitchy and returns my own profile image.

Comment: How do you know who your opponent is? What is in the `people` key? An array of user `_id`s?

Comment: And this array is in the user object??? That makes no sense - in that case one of the users is already known. Why not have a `Rooms` collection with `initiator` and `receiver` keys?

Comment: Uploaded images shows up with profile.profilepicId as Id reference, wrapped within `{{#with ChatPerson}}`, however, gravatars do not show up. They do appear on the user's profile page, wrapped in a `{{#with user}}` or `{{#with currentUser}}` field. User is referenced in a helper which finds id by the routed params. The user object cant be picked up in allRooms.js for the gravatar. I followed Meteorchef example written by you for Gravatar.

Comment: Best to ask a new question at this point with the code you're having trouble with. Glad my gravatar tutorial was useful to you!

Comment: yes actually same sentiments. Will do so. And yes I love your tutorial...insightful as always! Thank you.